# If a×b×c×d is 9, what is a+b+c+d ( a b c d are different integers)

Tags: education

If **a×b×c×d** is **9**, what is **a+b+c+d** ( a b c d are different integers)

Actually, I know the answer to this problem, (which is 1+(-1)+3+(-3)= 0), but I am not sure whether there is a systematic way to solve it.

I thought of separating the a b c and d to

a= 9*1/b*1/c*1/d
b=9*1/a*1/c*1/d
And so on...

However, it didn't work. Should I treat a b c d as a whole?

Edit:
Sorry I am on my phone so I can't use the formattings. Thanks for your understanding

Edit:
Thanks for all your help :).

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: A similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1595118/42969

Comment: Please use MathJax so that people can see it easily.

Comment: Sorry I am on my phone so I can't use MathJax

Comment: I have already written many posts with MathJax on a smartphone.

Comment: Prime factorization is $9=3^2$. Then $9$ has $2\cdot(2+1)=6$ distinct integer divisors. Using one of $\pm9$ multipliers excludes using any $\pm3$ and other $\pm9$ with only remaining multipliers $\pm1$, which makes total number of multipliers not greater than 3, which is not enough. Then one cannot  use $\pm9$, then one can use only $\pm1$ and $\pm3$, which count is exactly four.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> If $a, b, c, d$ are distinct integers which satisfies $abcd=9$, find $a+b+c+d$.

$a|9, b|9, c|9, d|9$.

The factors of $9$ is $-9, -3, -1, 1, 3, 9$.

WLOG, $a<b<c<d$.

If $a=-9:$ $bcd=-1$ for all distinct integers $b, c, d$, which has a contradiction.

If $b=9:$ $abc=1$ for all distinct integers $a, b, c$, which has a contradiction.

Therefore, $a=-3, b=-1, c=1, d=3.$

So, $a+b+c+d=0$.

Comment: Please do not post answers to duplicate questions and/or questions which show little or no effort from the OP. This is against the [Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) of the site.